# Does $V_1,V_2,V_3$ span $R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v_1=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
-1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$

Let $V_2= \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
-1\\
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$

Let $V_3= \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}
$

I combined these vectors into one large matrix and took the found the pivots.

Let $= \begin{bmatrix}
1 &  0 &  1\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
-1  &  0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$

The finding the pivots I got. I used the following operation switch R2 and R3, R1+R2, R3 SWITCH R2, R2+R4

AND R3 swtich R4 to get.

Let $= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & - 0
\end{bmatrix}
$

But how can I tell if it span R^4. R^4 is I think a vector with four entries. And I have four column so it should work..

Comment: No, simply because you need $n$ vectors to span an $n-$dimensional space.

Comment: Oh I did not know that. I read online it has something to with pivots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know that $\dim \mathbb R^4 = 4$. The minimum number of vectors you would need to span $\mathbb R^4$ is 4, hence three vectors will never span it regardless of their components.

Edit: Because you mentioned pivots, it's true that you could also do the mechanical elimination and find that there are less than 4 pivots. This is also independent of which three vectors you pick.

Answer (score 3):

In order for a set of vectors $\{v_{1},...,v_{m}\}$ to span a vector space of dimension $n$ we must have $m\geq n$.

In your situation you have a set of $3$ vectors and you're asking whether it spans a $4$ dimensional vector space. Since $3<4$ then this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

$3$ vectors cannot span a $4$-dimensional vector space.